# Fluid CSS Layout Question

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I am in the process of designing a website for a film that is being released, but I am having some problems with getting it to fit in all browser windows sizes and screen sizes. Essentially, the markup, for example for the splash page, has the films logo at the top of the page, a video (the films trailer) under it, then an enter button that takes the user to the homepage. All of these should be centered on all browser window sizes. However when I try different sizes etc. the content does not remain centered and the video moves off of it's background image. How would I fix that with CSS?

There are a few other pages as well i.e. synopsis, videos and then a page to donate to the project. I would like these to work in the same way, keeping content working correctly on all sizes. Thanks!

If you want to look at this and see what I mean, the link is http://rescuedthemovie.com/new/home. This is the dev page and has basically no final design so it is somewhat messy but you can see what I'm talking about.

jwinton

Comment: And I just got the splash page up and running. http://rescuedthemovie.com/new. Check the content there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the way you are positioning your elements on the page. Take a look at:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to whatever divs you want to be centered.  This should work on all browsers and will keep everything centered no matter the resolution.

```
#div {  
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I would suggest using this for the main content div, so everything is centered, then creating separate divs for the video, links, etc.  That way you can position those where you want them inside the centered div..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your design. I see the following problems.

- You have a `div id="container"` but the only thing it contains is the `div id="fotter"`. All the rest of the elements are "outside" the container div.
- You have a `div id="logo"` with a style of `margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 25%;`. How will this center it?
- Your `div id="slider"` has `position: relative; left: 26%; top: 3em;` which means that it is being pushed 26% from left and 3em from top of its origional position and leaving a "gap" where it was before.
- Your `h1` has a `margin: left; 300px;`. Where exactly you want it to be?
- Underneeth the `h1` you have `a` elements which contain `div` elements? This is like a block level element inside a in-line elements. Totally wrong. These all `a` elements should be inside a `div` and than that `div` should be positioned.
- Your `div#footer` is inside the
  `div#container`. The `div#foooter`
  has a style of `position: absolute`
  while the `div#container` does **NOT**
  have a `position: relative`. This
  causes 2 things. The `div#container`
  collapses as it does not have any
  content and the `div#fotter` is
  positioned relative to the browser
  window.
- you have 3 `div#recent`. The ID has to be unique. This is not allowed. Use calsses instaed.

I will give a skeloton on how to go about this.

**THE HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>Rescued: The Movie</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_styles.css">
</head>  
<body>  

<div id="container">

<div id="logo">
<a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com"><img src="http://rescuedthemovie.com/new/images/logo.png" alt="Rescued Logo" /> </a>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/home.html">home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/synopsis.html">synpsis</a></li>
<li><a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/videos.html">videos</a></li>
<li><a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/blog.html">blog</a></li>
<li><a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/partner.html">partner</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="slider">
<img src="http://rescuedthemovie.com/images/slides/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" />
<img src="http://rescuedthemovie.com/images/slides/slide2.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
<img src="http://rescuedthemovie.com/images/slides/slide3.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
</div>

<div id="blog">
<h1>NEWS</h1>
<div class="recent">
<h2>The Putnam's Adoption Journey</h2>
<a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/blog">My husband and I thought our family was complete. We had our two children (one boy and one girl) and were completely satisfied with that. Life was comfortable. My youngest had just started Kindergarten so I found myself with more free time than I had had in nine years! I was enjoying the freedom of grocery shopping without toddlers. But then God started stirring something in our hearts...</a>
</div>
<div class="recent">
<h2>God's Divine Leading: Part 3</h2>
<a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/blog">I remember feeling a little surprised that she had decided on adoption. I guess I just assumed that she would opt to keep her baby. I have to admit that I did wonder for a fleeting moment if perhaps the Lord was trying to lead Jurgen and I to adopt her baby, but then reasoned that a domestic adoption might be too risky. People might also think it  strange, since I was the one who encouraged her to consider adoption in the first place, rather than end her babyÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s life...</a>
</div>
<div class="recent">
<h2>God's Divine Leading: Part 2</h2>
<a href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/blog">When I awoke, I had an overwhelming desire to have a baby of our own. The dream was extraordinarily real and tangible, and I felt strongly that the Lord had given me this dream as an answer to my questions about pursuing adoption. I am not the type of person who normally bases my decisions on dreams, but this was different. It was as if the Lord Himself had dropped this desire into my heart...</a>
</div>
<a id="more" href="http://rescuedthemovie.com/blog">Read More</a>

</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>&copy;2011 Rescued</p>
</div>



</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

**THE CSS**

```
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

img
{
border: 0;
}

a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

body
{
background: url("http://rescuedthemovie.com/new/css/../images/blog_bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top #000;
}

div#container
{
width: 960px;
margin: 20px auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

div#logo
{
width: 850px;
height: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

div#logo a
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}

div#nav
{
background: url("http://rescuedthemovie.com/new/css/../images/nav.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
font-size: 25px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

div#nav ul
{
width: 900px;
margin: 10px auto;
}

div#nav ul li
{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 40px;
color: #FFF;
}

div#nav ul li a
{
color: #FFF;
}


div#slider
{
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 77px;
float: right;
position: relative; /*romove this in the final design*/ 
}

div#slider img /*romove this in the final design*/
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left; 0;
}

div#blog
{
float: left;
width: 450px;
color: #FFF;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

div#blog h1
{
margin: 20px 0;
}

div#blog a#more
{
float: right;
color: red;
}

div.recent
{
margin: 20px 0;
border: 1px solid #555;
padding: 5px;
}

div.recent h2
{
font-weight: bold;
color: #777;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.recent a
{
color: #FFF;

}

div#footer
{
clear: both;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
font: 25px;
margin: 20px auto;
}

div#footer p
{
font-size: 25px;
}
```

This offcouse is an fixed width layout. But you can easily change it to fluid or estalic. This is how it looks

[image: Layout]

Comment: @jwinton: You keep changing the site. The nav is new. Anyway I added it.

Comment: @jwinton: You could atleast get back as if it worked for you or not.